# Rails drag and drop change object attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have two models; Collections and Images

Collection model

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
end
```

Image model

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :collection    
  mount_uploader :file, ImageUploader   
end
```

A Collection has_many :images

In my edit_collection view Im showing all images as thumbnails in a grid view.  At the moment I dont have any way to send an image to another collection.  Since I don't want to force the user to edit images one at a time, I thought this would be a good opportunity to use drag and drop functionality to change the collection that the image belongs to.

Im thinking that on my edit_collection page, which has the grid of image thumbnails, I would have a list of collections on the side.  Allowing the user to drag an image thumbnail onto a collection to change collection_id value of the image.

Since Im still pretty noobish, Im looking for a tutorial that addresses changing an attribute in this manner, or perhaps a gem, or any advice.  So far all the material Ive found seems to be focused on using drag and drop to change the hierarchy of list.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Implementing draggable functionality is going to require Javascript of some sort (I don't know of any gems that abstract this away), so make sure you're familiar with how [Javascript/Ajax is used in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) first.

Probably the most popular solution for this kind of thing in a broad sense is a combination of jQuery [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/). You can get these into your Rails app by using the `jquery-ui-rails` gem ([more instructions here](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails)). You'll need to require the needed modules in your `app/assets/application.js` file:

```
//= require jquery
...
//= require jquery.ui.draggable
//= require jquery.ui.droppable
...
//= require_tree .
```

Basically you'll want an action on your controller that takes a couple of params (the image `id` and `collection_id` you want to move it to would be a good idea in this case), finds that image and changes its collection based on these params, then renders a Javascript or JSON response to tell the browser that the change has been made (or not) - that's assuming you want to stay on the page. e.g:

```
def change_collection
  @image = Image.find(params[:id])
  @image.collection_id = params[:collection_id]
  if @image.save
    render json: ..., status: ...
  else
    render json: ..., status: ...
  end
end
```

This is just an example to give you an idea, you probably don't want to assign a param directly like that because of security reasons.

You'll need a route that points to that action, e.g:

```
resources :images do
  patch 'change_collection', on: :member 
end
```

Then you need to implement the Javascript side of things. Read the [API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/) for draggable and droppable to see what methods/events are available, and tweak to your liking. You'll probably be doing something like this:

```
$( ".html_class_representing_your_images" ).draggable();

$( ".html_class_representing_your_collections" ).droppable({
  drop: function() {
    Ajax request to the route we just made goes here
  }
});
```

You can find plenty of information on how to make an Ajax request using jQuery elsewhere (including how to use success/failure handlers), but I'll just let you know that you will need to find a way to get your `ids` from your DOM elements, the conventional way being to supply them with a `data` attribute in your views (mentioned in the guide I linked at the top).

In the future, if you add more fancy features like this and your app starts getting sufficiently complicated on the frontend that you can't keep your Javascript organized, then you may want to consider a frontend framework like Backbone.js rather than relying on the DOM so much.

Anyway, I hope that's enough to get you started at least.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use ajax for this.

So, when they drag the picture into a new collection, update the picture locally to have that new id, and also send an ajax request to a new controller action that would take care of this. You'd pass in the old picture id and the new collection to update the required attributes.

Due to your tags, I assume you already know how this goes, but for example:

On the front-end side, you could do something like this whenever a picture gets dragged into a new collection.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/images/8',
    type: 'PUT',
    data: { new_collection: collection_id },
    success: function (response) {
        //do whatever you need, like maybe assigning the new id to the picture you have locally.
    },
    error: function (response) {
        // do whatever you'd do if it failed, like maybe ask them to try again. Since user is just dragging, ideally this would never happen, but perhaps they don't have internet connection. Again, at this point it becomes a matter of saying they can't do that without internet connection or maybe caching it locally, telling them you've cached it and that you'd go forward and do that when they have internet in the future. Tougher, but cooler and maybe nice to learn.
    }
});
```

On the rails side, in `routes.rb` you'd have something like:

`resources :images` which would include the route above.

Then, in the controller `ImagesController` you'd have something of the following.

```
def update
    @image = Image.find(params[:id])

    @image.assign_attributes(collection_id: params[:new_collection])

    if @image.save
        render json: @image, status: 200
    else
        render json: @image.errors.full_messages #not sure if right off the top of my head.
    end
end
```

Basically, that is how you'd go ahead and do it.